# Force IE9 Document Standards in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, standards

When I view my website in IE10, it seems that it's automatically forcing IE8 document standards. However, I would like it to use IE9 standards, when being viewed in IE10.

Is there a way to do this?

The page has `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top.

**EDIT:** It turned out that I had `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` in the page header, which was causing the page to render in IE8 document mode. Changing this to IE=9 fixed the issue.

Comment: Why do you want IE9 mode rather than IE10 mode????

Comment: *"Changing this to IE=9 fixed the issue."* Or better yet, remove it entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use the `X-UA` meta tag. The `X-UA`-Compatible meta tag allows you to choose what version of Internet Explorer the page should be rendered as.

You specify the user agent and version to use in the contents of the tag. The current options you have for the content are: `IE=5`, `IE=EmulateIE7`, `IE=7`, `IE=EmulateIE8`, `IE=8`, `IE=EmulateIE9`, `IE=9`, `IE=edge`.

Emulating the version tells the browser to use the `DOCTYPE` to determine how to render content. Pages without a `DOCTYPE` will be rendered in [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). If you tell it to use the browser version without emulating (i.e. `IE=7`) the browser will render the page in standards mode whether or not there is a `DOCTYPE` declaration. `IE=edge` tells Internet Explorer to use the highest mode available to that version of IE. Internet Explorer 8 can support up to IE8 modes, IE9 can support IE9 modes and so on.

I think you need this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `X-UA` meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

And I don't know why you want to do this, as IE 10 is far more excellent than any of the previous versions of IE, if you are testing, you can press `F12` and change the mode

Comment: *"And I don't know why you want to do this"* The OP said why in the questino: For some reason, IE10 is acting like IE8. (What he really wants to do, presumably, is make it act like IE10.)

Comment: +1 for the correct answer to the question that was asked, and also +1 for "I don't know why you want to do this"... Why would anyone ever want to use IE9 mode in IE10??? Just make it work in IE10 mode like it should do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess he has turned on the dev mode and changed the settings, also WHY IE10 behaves like 8... I wonder...